# InnoSetup no longer allows user to pick installation directory?

Tags: inno-setup

I just upgraded to Inno Setup 5.9 and I noticed that users no longer can select installation directory if the user already installed an earlier version.

I want Inno Setup to always show the installation directory dialog - however, i is excellent if he default value is what the current/last installation uses.

How do I achieve this? I am using this:

```
AppName=example
AppVerName=example
AppCopyright=example
DefaultDirName={pf}\example\example
DefaultGroupName=example\example
OutputBaseFilename=example
AppPublisher=examle
AppPublisherURL=http://example.com
AppSupportURL=http://example.com
AppUpdatesURL=http://example.com
AppVersion=8.0.0
UninstallDisplayName=example
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\example.exe
AllowNoIcons=true
WindowVisible=false
UsePreviousSetupType=true
UsePreviousGroup=true
EnableDirDoesntExistWarning=true
OutputDir=output\
LicenseFile=..\..\compiled\license.txt
AppMutex=
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=true
AlwaysShowGroupOnReadyPage=true
Compression=lzma
DisableStartupPrompt=true
ShowLanguageDialog=yes
AppID=
PrivilegesRequired=admin
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
DisableDirPage=false
```

Comment: Though as you actually set the `DisableDirPage=false` (`no` is the correct value, but `false` should work too), you should actually get the page on all systems.

Comment: i am not completely sure - but it works now second test around after I added DisableDirPage - I added and tested that on my own before posting - but on my initial testing the behavior did not change, thus i posted. Not sure if to close this question now or if you provide it as an answer accept it?